# Can long-running cells in iPython/Jupyter report runtime status info without cluttering the cell output?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I'm writing some functions in a Jupyter notebook to prepare data, but they can take quite a while to run.

```
In  [*]: print "hello"
         df['expensive_col'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

It would be useful if `myfunc` would print status information such that I see how far into the execution it is. The downside of this is that it would seriously clutter the Jupyter output cell.

```
In  [*]: print hello
         df['expensive_col'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)

hello
ix0
ix1
ix2
...
ix999
...
noisy output
...
```

Is there a way to print status updates from the long-running Jupyter cell in such a way to keep from cluttering the output cell?

For example, I could wipe everything printed by calling `IPython.display.clear_output()` but I might want to do a more targeted wipe, keeping stuff from before my expensive (hello, in the above example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple thing you could do is to invoke the `print` function with the `end` parameter set to carriage return instead of newline, like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    print('progress %i' % i, end='\r')
    # things happen here
```

It effectively writes over the previous line, without cluttering the output field.

For a more advanced approach (and fancy looking progress bars!) check out the [tqdm project](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).